# Angular 5 BehaviorSubject not working for boolean value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, behavior

I am trying to practice behaviorsubject in angular 5. I am written a small app with two components and want to change the value in both of them at once but the value is not changing. BehaviorSubject should change the value in all the components. Please help me understand.

## Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class TestserviceService {

public isAdmin = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
cast = this.isAdmin.asObservable();

constructor() { }

changeAdmin(){
  this.isAdmin.next(!this.isAdmin);
}

}
```

## Component One

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ TestserviceService } from '../../testservice.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.css']

})
   export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  constructor(private testservice: TestserviceService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.testservice.cast.subscribe(data => this.isAdmin = data);

  }

  changeValue(){
    this.testservice.changeAdmin();
    console.log(this.isAdmin);
  }

}
```

## Component One html

```
<button (click)="changeValue()">Click Me</button>
<p>
  one {{isAdmin}}
</p>
```

## Component Two

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestserviceService } from '../../testservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  templateUrl: './two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./two.component.css']
})
    export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  constructor(private testservice: TestserviceService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.testservice.cast.subscribe(data => this.isAdmin = data);
    console.log("two "+this.isAdmin);
  }


}
```

Comment: try moving that `console.log` inside your subscribe block in component 2

Comment: Shouldn't `this.isAdmin.next(!this.isAdmin);` be `this.isAdmin.next(!this.isAdmin.value);`

Comment: @cyberpirate92 thank you. It works. Pleas add it as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
changeAdmin(){
  this.isAdmin.next(!this.isAdmin);
}
```

Should be

```
changeAdmin(){
  this.isAdmin.next(!this.isAdmin.value);
}
```

`this.isAdmin` is a `BehaviorSubject` and you were trying to set `!thisAdmin` which evaluates to `false`

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4gihn2)

Answer (score 2):

Change your service to :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable()
export class SharedServiceService {

  constructor() { }
  public isAdmin = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  cast = this.isAdmin.asObservable();

  changeAdmin(){
    this.isAdmin.next(!this.isAdmin.value);
  }
}
```

It should be `this.isAdmin.value` because `this.admin` will only be behaviourSubject's object

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txqvn7?file=app%2Fshared-service.service.ts)